# How to use SQL Group By to select all the records in the first group?

Tags: sql, group-by

I have a table with columns `COUNTRY, STATE, CITY, NAME`. I group by on `COUNTRY, STATE, CITY`.

How to write a query to return all records for the first 1 or 10 groups?

group: records with the same COUNTRY, STATE and CITY.

| id | COUNTRY | STATE | CITY | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | CA | SF | Adam |
| 2 | US | CA | SF | Ben |
| 3 | US | TX | Austin | Carry |
| 4 | US | TX | Houston | Don |

I want to return:

| id | COUNTRY | STATE | CITY | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | CA | SF | Adam |
| 2 | US | CA | SF | Ben |

Comment: Help us help you - share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it

Comment: First group - according to what? count, id, a name?

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.

Answer (score 0):

If your dbms supports `DENSE_RANK()`, you could use inner query with `DENSE_RANK()` and take only rows with said rank equal 1 (or not more than 10 if you want first 10 groups)

```sql
select COUNTRY, STATE, CITY, NAME
from(
    select
        COUNTRY, STATE, CITY, NAME,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNTRY, STATE, CITY) dr
    from my_table
) inn where dr <= 1 -- or 10 if you want ten
```